# Driver problem with Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, disk, lvm

I have a password set at boot up and I get this error after I enter my password:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 is not ready
```

What caused this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is trying to mount your encrypted `swap` partition (encrypted `swap` is required for encrypted `$HOME` directories to be usable), and it seems that the initialization is taking too long. Your system will come up normally, but without that `swap` space. If the `free` command shows less `swap` than expected, you can re-initialize `swap` by logging in, and

```
sudo /usr/sbin/cryptdisks_start  ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```